# Analysis on Binomial data with a conjugate beta prior.

Tags: probability

Suppose we perform an analysis on binomial data with a conjugate beta prior. Our prior has a mean `0.4` and effective sample size `5`.

We then observe `10` trials with `6` successes. That is, the data mean is `0.6`. Let `^∗` denote the posterior mean for , the probability of success.

Which of the following is true about `^∗`?

```
- ^∗≤0.4
- 0.4<^∗<0.5
- ^∗=0.6
- 0.5<^∗<0.6
- ^∗≥0.6
```